# Python - SMTP mail sending script is triggering multiple mails even though mail sending function is not called

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am new to python. I had a requirement to check the file modified date and compare with current date and send mail if the modified date is older than current date. Below is the script.

```
import os.path
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTPException
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    filename="pySysLog.log",
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s -  %(name)s- %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    )


def sendmail():
    sender = 'sntspo@in.inm.com'
    receivers = ['Guru.kar@inm.com']
    message = """From: SMT Support <sntspo@in.inm.com>
To: Guruprasad <Guru.kar@inm.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: PIR File Not Recived from GDMIS

Hi All,</br>
</br>
Today, PIR Feed File is not received from GDMIS</br>
</br>
Regards,</br>
SMT Team
"""

    try:
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('ni.gelay.inm.com')
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
        smtpObj.quit()
        logging.info("Successfully sent email")
    except SMTPException:
        logging.info("Error: unable to send email")


def checkFile():
    uplDate = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("/home/sadm/batchscript/Report.txt")))
    currentDate = str(datetime.now())
    logging.info("Modified date of file  " + uplDate)
    logging.info("Current date  " + currentDate)
    if uplDate < currentDate:
        logging.info("File is not received from MIS")
        sendmail()
    else:
        logging.info("File is received from MIS")


checkFile()
```

I am facing the following issues:

1. Even though sendmail() function is called only if condition is satisfied but mail is triggering
2. mail is triggering not once but multiple times

please help

Comment: You're comparing strings. Try changing them to integers and then compare.

Comment: Please check the formatting of your question before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
uplDate = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file_path))
    # uplDate = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("HCLNotesInstall.log"))
    currentDate = datetime.now()
    logging.info("Modified date of file  " + str(uplDate.date()))
    logging.info("Current date  " + str(currentDate.date()))
    if uplDate.date() < currentDate.date():
```

`uplDate.date() < currentDate.date()` uses a date to compare instead of a string.